# Three Column Layout side columns elastic middle fixed

Tags: html, css

I was wondering if anyone knows how to have a fixed width of the centered div and have the right and left div elastic on either side of the centered div. The centered div has a min-width and max-width css properties aswell.

Comment: http://www.whathaveyoutried.com ?

Answer (score 1):

Try to add the code what you tried when you post a question.

**HTML**

```
<div class = "container">
    <div class = "fluid">
        I am fluid
    </div>

    <div class = "fixed">
        I'm Fixed! 
    </div>

    <div class = "fluid">        
        I am fluid
    </div>
</div>
```

​
**CSS**

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    font-family: 'Arial', 'Helvetica', Sans-Serif;
}
.container {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.container > div {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
}
.fixed {
    min-width: 200px; max-width:300px;
    background: rgb(34, 177, 77);
    color: white;
}
.fluid {
    background: rgb(0, 162, 232);
}
​
```

**[DEMO LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/SHnc9/14/)**

Answer (score 0):

I did it with flexbox, but can't do it with table-cell becouse side columns width depends on side column content. So my code looks like

https://codepen.io/ArunsKas/pen/owveer

**HTML**

```
<div class="flex">
  <div class="flex-children">asdaaa asdaaaasdaaa asdaaa asdaaa</div>
  <div class="flex-children-fixed">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempora et nisi harum eaque quas similique esse voluptas? Expedita in vitae, vel unde deleniti hic dolores rerum. Aliquam quos quidem quae.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-children">ddey</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.flex {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.flex-children {
  width: calc((100% - 200px)/2 - 10px);
  background: red;
}
.flex-children-fixed {
  width: 200px;
  background: red;
}
```