# Mix percent and pixel for 3-col layout

Tags: html, css, pixel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Three Column Layout side columns elastic middle fixed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13248570/three-column-layout-side-columns-elastic-middle-fixed)

I am building a webpage with a wrapper of 90% of the screen width. In the wrapper I will have 3 columns.

- Wrapper is 90% width of the screensize.
- Middle column is 500PX
- Left column is 60% of the remaining space after the middlecolumn.
- Right column is 40% of the remaining space after the middlecolumn.

I am having problem with how to set the left and right columns to the correct width.
Do anyone know a smart way to solve this.

[image]

Comment: I use float:left on all the 3 columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this from javascript.
First you have to get the height in px of the top div

```
var top = $('#top').width();
```

After this you have to calculate the diference between that width and the 500px that has the middle div from the bottom:

```
var sum = top - 500;
```

After this you have to calculate the width of the left and right bottom divs + margin (i've set it to 10px):

```
var left = (sum * 60)/100 - 10;
var right = (sum * 40)/100 - 10;
```

In final you have to apply the width on the 2 divs:

```
$('#left').width(left);
$('#right').width(right);
```

You can check out the example that i made here: http://jsfiddle.net/paulalexandru21/LceLw/1/

PS. if you don't see the layout well, you need to drag it and you will see all the 3 colums exactly how you wanted them to be.